# ReflectionException in Container.php line 719: Class bindings does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Recently I am working with laravel 5.4 (i worked with laravel 5.2 before) for a project. I have simple route in my **api.php**

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
return "test";
});
```

When I tried to access this url from **postman** with the url **/api/test** , I get the following error-

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 719:
Class bindings does not exist
```

I didn't face this kind of error when working with api in **laravel 5.2**. Now I am stuck here. Hope someone have a solution, Thanks.

Comment: You do not show us all of your code. Read about [Route Model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding) because it's probably throws an exception.

Comment: its a fresh laravel 5.4 project and have a single route in api.php what i have written, when i tried to access from postman, i got the error

Comment: got the solution, somehow i was missing this line in my routeMiddleware  'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

Answer (score 0):

Late but, in my case paying attention on the function mapWebRoutes in the RouteServiceProvider.php is where I found my solution. The option 'web' was what I need.

```
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```